# How do I get rid of virtualbox so it isn't stopping me from updating via GPG error [...] NO_PUBKEY [...]?

Tags: apt, updates, kubuntu, virtualbox

I've found tons of guides on how to fix the NO_PUBKEY issue, but what I really want is to get rid of VirtualBox because I never got it working and don't need it yet. So I tried to get rid of it via a guide. Here's the full terminal log:

```
username@username-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                                                        
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                        
Hit:4 https://repo.nordvpn.com//deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease                                               
Get:5 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease [4,428 B]                                 
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                            
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
Err:5 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF
Reading package lists... Done       
W: GPG error: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF
E: The repository 'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
username@username-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'virtualbox' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
```

Okay, how about another guide?:

```
username@username-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt-get purge virtualbox*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-ext-pack' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-x11' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-ose' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-ose-fuse' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-additions-iso' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-modules' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-utils' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-utils-hwe' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-modules' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-qt' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-2.0' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-2.1' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-2.2' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-3.0' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-3.1' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-3.2' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-4.0' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-4.1' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-4.2' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-4.3' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-5.0' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-5.1' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-5.2' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-6.0' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-6.1' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-source' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-dkms' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Package 'virtualbox-ose' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-ose-fuse' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-6.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-6.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-5.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-5.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-5.0' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-dkms' instead of 'virtualbox-modules'
Package 'virtualbox-2.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-2.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-2.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-3.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-3.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-3.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-4.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-4.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-4.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-4.3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-dkms' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-ext-pack' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-additions-iso' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-utils' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-utils-hwe' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-x11' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-qt' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-source' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
```

That doesn't look like it did anything... but let's try updating again just in case:

```
username@username-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://repo.nordvpn.com//deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease  
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Get:4 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease [4,428 B]              
Err:4 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease                        
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
Reading package lists... Done      
W: GPG error: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF
E: The repository 'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about a package named `virtualbox` (or `virtualbox-6.1` or similar), but about the *repository* offering those packages.

Packages in a repository can be cryptographically signed. To check these signatures, `apt` needs the *public key* associated with the repository. When you set up the repository, you didn't properly configure a public key for it. That's what `apt` is complaining about:

```
Err:5 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF
(...)
W: GPG error: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF
E: The repository 'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

You've got two ways to solve it: If you want to keep using Virtualbox from this repository, you need to supply `apt` with the public key for the repository. Or you can remove the repository, which is what I understand you want to do.

For this, you need to look through the list of repositories your have configured and remove the corresponding entry. It should be either in `/etc/apt/sources.list` directly, or in an individual file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, depending how you added the repository originally.

Comment: Okay that took care of it; I deleted the "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/oracle-virtualbox-2016.gpg] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy contrib" from the bottom of that sources.list file, and everything is back to the way it was. 


Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily remove the VirtualBox  repository. Either using Software & Updates GUI, or by running

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox*
```

This command will work if you installed VB from a deb file. If you manually added the source, you need to find where the source is located, e.g. `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox*': No such file or directory